# Can I set rspec --format documentation as the default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

[Per the Rspec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/command-line/format-option), by default when you run `rspec` you get the progress formatter (looks like this: ".....").

There is another formatting option `rspec --format documentation` that goes through each test one by one. My question: how can I enable `--format documentation` by default without having to type it in the command line every time?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Option 1

Add it to `.rspec` file (or create one in the project's root directory) - options added to it will be applied to every test run within current project:

```
# .rspec
--color
--format documentation
```

## Option 2

Add it to `RSpec.configure` block:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.formatter = :documentation
end
```

## Option 3

Specify rspec's options globally by adding them to `~/.rspec`.

Comment: You can also add this to your global config (e.g. `~/.rspec` on Mac)

Comment: Andrey, I was trying to add that line to the .rspec file but it was giving me a syntax error. I'm guessing I was placing the code in the wrong place. The block of code below found me success.

Edit: Cool, going to accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, for the help!

Answer (score 8):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.color = true
  config.formatter = :documentation
  config.order = 'default'
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own personal RSpec settings by creating a `~/.rspec` file:

```
--color
--format documentation
```

The project `.rspec` file should only contain the minimum settings required to run the spec suite to avoid developer wars.

Comment: This is a somewhat opinionated answer but I would NOT use `RSpec.configure` to set the format either as this really is a matter of preference.